# sudo: PAM authentication error: Failure setting user credentials

Tags: linux, pam

I am not able to run sudo command. Every time i run with sudo I get the **PAM error**, Failure setting user credentials.

```
> sudo su 
[sudo] password for userX: 
sudo: PAM authentication error: Failure setting user credentials
```

Here is the error with screenshot

[image]

I tried looking for hints in man access.conf i could not find anything. Any leads would be helpful

Comment: Have you or anyone modified the PAM files for this system?

Comment: Not sure, I had a docker service running few days back. But i have no idea that it did modify or not.